# PostgreSQL PERFORM not triggering events

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have created a trigger for INSERT events.

```
CREATE TABLE TBLEXAMPLE
(
    KEY1 CHARACTER VARYING(10) NOT NULL,
    KEY2 CHARACTER VARYING(14) NOT NULL,
    VALUE1 CHARACTER VARYING(20),
    VALUE2 CHARACTER VARYING(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT TBLEXAMPLE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (KEY1, KEY2)
);

CREATE TRIGGER TBLEXAMPLE_AFTER
AFTER INSERT
ON TBLEXAMPLE
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE NOTIFY();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NOTIFY() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify(CAST('myEvent' as text), row_to_json(NEW)::text);
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE COST 100;
```

However, doing an insert does not trigger any events.

```
INSERT INTO TBLEXAMPLE(KEY1, KEY2, VALUE1, VALUE2) VALUES ('k1', 'k2', 'v1', 'v2');
```

Events are triggered in case I explicitly notify from console :-

```
NOTIFY myEvent, '{"id": 3, "state": "active"}';
```

Comment: try to debug with some RAISE NOTICE; for example RAISE NOTICE 'NEW = %', NEW; may be there are an error with row_to_json or CAST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) of the `NOTIFY` command is

```
NOTIFY channel [ , payload ]
```

where `channel` is a [Postgres identifier.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) Hence the channel in

```
NOTIFY myEvent, '{"id": 3, "state": "active"}';
```

is automatically converted to `myevent`, while the function `pg_notify()` does not do the conversion. Use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NOTIFY() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('myevent', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE COST 100;
```

or generally, do not use cameCase in Postgres identifiers.